# Nivo slider won't load properly after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, nivo-slider

I have this problem with my website

my main page structure is this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
var escapedHash;

function findHash() {
    if(window.location.hash) {
        //$("#content").html("Loading...");

        escapedHash = window.location.hash.replace("#!", "");
        //alert(escapedHash);

        $.get("data.php?_escaped_fragment_=" + escapedHash, function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    findHash();
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    findHash();
});
</script>

</head>

<body>


<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#!page-1">Page-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#!page-2">Page-2</a></li>
...
<li><a href="#!page-n">Page-n</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

this loads data from this array data.php

```
<?php

$hash_frag = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];

$content = array(

"page-1" => 'content page 1',

"page-2" => 'content page 2',

...

"page-n" => 'content page n'



);

if(isset($hash_frag)) {
    echo $content[$hash_frag];
}

?>
```

Nivo slider is in one of this page and if i refresh the pare URL/#!page-n (where page-n contains the slider) everything works perfectly.

As soon as i call another page everything goes as expected loading the content from the other page and substituting the slider. Ok all good.

Now if i try to load the slider from another page it just won't load, or better it will go into the div but without showing. I have already linked the initialisation of nivo.slider on click, i tried to pu it in the array or on the main page...no difference.

Can anybody help me to fix this huge mystery for me?

thanks heaps
Emanuele

Comment: you did not import nivo css and js

Comment: I did import the js...but i forgot the css!!!! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you did not import nivo **css** and **js** plugins after `<script src="http../jquery.min.js..`